How to solve ODE $f''(t) + tf'(t) -f(t) = 0$ using laplace transforms
I am trying to solve ODE $f''(t) + tf'(t) -f(t) = 0$ using laplace transforms
My Attempts :
I have used laplace transform on both sides to get $\mathcal L{f''(t)+tf'(t)-f(t)} = \mathcal L {0}$
Using $\mathcal L f''(t) = s^{2}\mathcal Lf(t)-sf(0)-f'(0)$ and $\mathcal L tf'(t) = - \mathcal L f(t) -s \mathcal L f'(t)$
As well as given information that $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = 1$
I can get $(s^{2}-2) \mathcal L f(t)-s\mathcal L f'(t) = 1$
But I am not sure how to proceed given that the second laplace transform is a derivative here.

See Derivative Property in the table at Laplace Transform: Properties and theorems.

using the properties @StevenClark sent you :
Let $g(t) = f'(t) $ so $$ \mathcal{L}\left{ g\left(t\right)\right} =\mathcal{L}\left{ f'\left(t\right)\right} =G\left(s\right)=F\left(s\right)-f\left(0^{-}\right)\tag{using derivative property} $$ and $$ \mathcal{L}\left{ tf'\left(t\right)\right} =\mathcal{L}\left{ tg\left(t\right)\right} =-G'\left(s\right)=-\frac{d}{ds}\left{ F\left(s\right)-f\left(0^{-}\right)\right} =-F'\left(s\right)\tag{using the Frequency domain derivative } $$

Thanks, but  I still don't see how this helps as isn't this now a derivative of the laplace transform and not a laplace transform of the derivative? I also tried introducing a new variable to do another set of laplace transforms but it gets super messy and complicated.

This reduces your ODE from a 3rd order to a 1st order having only $F'(s) $ and $F(s)$.
If you can find a solution to this new differential equation in the frequency domain, you can then use the inverse transform and find a solution to the original ODE.
$$ =s^{2}F\left(s\right)-sf\left(0^{-}\right)-f'\left(0^{-}\right)-F'\left(s\right)-F\left(s\right)=0\Rightarrow $$
$$ F\left(s\right)\left[s^{2}-1\right]-F'\left(s\right)=1\Rightarrow $$
if you can solve the differential equation : $$ y\left[x^{2}-1\right]-y'=1$$
This should be fairly similar.

@DannyBlozrov I subsequently realized the notation $$-s, \mathcal{L} f'(t)$$ in the question which I interpreted as $$-s, \mathcal{L}_t\leftf'(t)\right$$ is misleading since I believe it should really be $$-s \frac{\partial, \left(\mathcal{L}_tf(t)\right)}{\partial s}.$$

@StevenClark I just used the standard notation as in the wiki u sent, I think OP shouldn't keep variables from the frequency domain $(s)$and the time domain$(t)$ in the same equation, only makes it harder to interpret

This is what I get. But can't find inverse Laplace transform for final result.
\begin{align*}
f^{\prime\prime}+tf^{\prime}-f  & =0\\
f\left(  0\right)    & =0\\
f^{\prime}\left(  0\right)    & =1
\end{align*}
Using $L\left(  t^{n}f\left(  t\right)  \right)  =\left(  -1\right)  ^{n}
\frac{d}{ds}F^{\left(  n\right)  }\left(  s\right)  $ property, then $L\left(
tf^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  \right)  =-\frac{d}{ds}L\left(  f^{\prime}\left(
t\right)  \right)  $. But  Laplace transform of $f^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  $
is $sF\left(  s\right)  -f\left(  0\right)  $. Hence the ode becomes
$$
\left(  s^{2}F-sf\left(  0\right)  -f^{\prime}\left(  0\right)  \right)
+\left(  -\frac{d}{ds}\left(  sF\left(  s\right)  -f\left(  0\right)  \right)
\right)  -F=0
$$
Plugin $f\left(  0\right) = 0,f^{\prime}\left(  0\right)  =1$ the above becomes
\begin{align*}
\left(  s^{2}F-1\right)  -\frac{d}{ds}sF\left(  s\right)  -F  & =0\\
s^{2}F-1-\left(  sF^{\prime}+F\right)  -F  & =0\\
s^{2}F-1-sF^{\prime}-F-F  & =0\\
s^{2}F-1-sF^{\prime}-2F  & =0\\
-sF^{\prime}+\left(  s^{2}-2\right)  F  & =1\\
F^{\prime}+\frac{\left(  2-s^{2}\right)  }{s}F  & =\frac{-1}{s}%
\end{align*}
This is linear ode in $F\left(  s\right)  $ whose solution is
$$
F=\frac{1}{s^{2}}+\frac{1}{s^{2}}c_{1}e^{\frac{s^{2}}{2}}%
$$
Hence $f\left(  t\right)  $ is the inverse Laplace transform of the above. Use
initial condition to find $c_{1}$. But can't find inverse Laplace transform.

$f(0)=0=\underset{s\to \infty }{\text{lim}}s F(s)= c_1\cdot\infty \implies c_1=0$
Hence $F(s)=\frac{1}{s^2}$ and $f(t)=\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left\frac{1}{s^2}\right=t$
